# Will Update SQL In Automation Studio Remove Records That Don't Satisfy Requirement?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I am attempting to automate our payment failures to alert consumers their subscription payment hasn't processed. My initial thought was to run a SQL activity once a day and inject new records into a payment journey that has a wait step at the end allowing them to reenter after a certain period of time. My question is, will the "Update" SQL activity removed records from the data extension when the requirement isn't satisfied?

For example, run query on 5/1 and payment failed. Run again on 5/2 and the payment has been resolved, will that user still be in the original table or removed? Here is the query i am working from:

```
SELECT pay.payment_status
    , pay.lead_id
    , pay.[Subscription Number]
    , pay.draft_date
    , pay.stop_notification
    , pay.Email
    , pay.Phone
    , pay.[Phone Formatted]
    , account.Status
FROM "Payment History" pay
    LEFT JOIN "Subscription Data" account
    ON account.[Subscription Number] = pay.[Subscription Number]
WHERE 
        pay.payment_status <> ''
        AND pay.payment_status <> ' ' 
        AND NOT pay.payment_status IS NULL
        AND LEN(pay.payment_status) > 0
        AND NOT pay.payment_status LIKE '%Approved%'
        AND account.Status in ('Active', 'ACTIVE')
```

My current work around is to overwrite the table every run, but, that isnt the ideal way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Updates values in the target where field name matches field returned
>   by SQL Query for rows whose Primary Key the SQL query returns. Rows
>   returned by SQL Query whose Primary Key does not exist in the target
>   are appended.

[**Use the SQL Query Activity**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_the_sql_query_activity.htm&type=5)

A query activity with an action of Update will not remove records from the data extension.