# SQL Query Activity Update vs. Overwrite Target DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a scenario in which we:

1. SQL Query to Sendable DE. SQL Selects Contacts based on a specific Status.
2. Fire an event in an automation to inject to a Journey

We need to hold the injected contacts in the journey for 60 days to assure these do not repeat.

2 questions:

**a. Overwrite Target DE.**

If status changes on next run - the contact that started the journey will no longer exist in the DE (overwirtten) - will he be ejected? Or those who start - will finish?

I need them to finish.

**b. Update Target DE**

If I choose Update, and status changes - certain contacts will no longer be included in results.

So this means they will stay in the DE and re-enter after 60 days?
That's what I understand from the answer here:
[Will Update SQL In Automation Studio Remove Records That Don't Satisfy Requirement?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265080/will-update-sql-in-automation-studio-remove-records-that-dont-satisfy-requireme)

I don't want them to re-enter - their status is no longer up to date in the DE.

If the Overwrite doesn't eject them from the journey - it will be the correct configuration. Can someone please confirm / propose a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: The alternative would be to use Update, and have another Automated activity to "clean" prospects once in a while, but we'd like to avoid it if unnecessary.

Comment: Once a contact is injected into a journey the entry source DE has no effect on the subscriber in the journey